# Copying table data continously in excel workbook

Tags: windows, windows-7, excel, vba

I have data in a tabular format range from A2:O30

I need to copy this table data by clicking a macro button into range Q2:A33 and so on

I used this code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  If Range("Q2").Value = "" Then
      Range("Q2:AE33").Value = Range("A2:O33").Value
  Else
      Range("Q2:A33" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
      .Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("A2:O33").Value
  End If
End Sub
```

It copies fine, but when i click on the button next time it shows me an error. 
From the next time we pressed the button it should copy the table range next to AE i.e from AG2:AU33

It should copy continuously by clicking the button.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the range in the Else statement incorrectly. Also, use a range variable to save having to say `Range("A2:O33")` all the time - something like this:

```
Dim rngCopy as Range
Set rngCopy = Range("A2:O33")

Cells("A" & Activesheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
```